# Calling javascript function on hyperlink clcick

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am printing a hyperlink using Response.Write as follows
Response.Write("Update");

I need a JavaScript function to be called on hyperlink click.

Please solve this.....

Comment: have you tried solving this problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="func()">Hyperlink</a>

function func(){
   alert('func');
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LE8Lp/).

Comment: Here i have a variable as string v=RowNo.ToSString();  Can i send this variable as a parametrt o javascript function like <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="func(v)">Hyperlink</a>

Comment: "string v" is a server side var. You can create a js var with the server content and access it in the func without passing it as a param.

Comment: Actually its a row number which is assigned dynamically on a certain condition i.e a click on Hyperlink on row no 68(for ex), the value at(68,12)"12- column" should be changed. So to perform this the variable has to be passed as a parameter.